# Which server version (64-bit) of Ubuntu will be suitable (for Gazebo and Ros Simulation)?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, server, nvidia, 64-bit

I  am using **Dell Precision T7500 Chassis** (Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5606 2.13GHz, 8M cache, 4.8 GT/s QPI, Turbo, HT, 4C,NVIDIA Tesla C2050 Graphic Card,1GB NVIDIA Quadro 600,Dual Monitor,1DP & 1DVI) **as server**. If any one has work experience or idea in this plz let me know, **which server version of Ubuntu will be best suitable.**

Comment: How much RAM do you have available?

Comment: Dell Precision T7500 with 8 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Since the CPU does support 64-bit architecture and you have 8GB of RAM, I'd recommend using the **64-bit Version** of Ubuntu. Usually you need a minimum of about 4GB RAM for 64-bit, but 8 should be more than enough.